# Emscripten Using libC Socket, Assertion failed: undefined

Tags: emscripten

I have problem with example called "test_sockets_partial_client.c".
All expect read data from server working, browser connect to server, send data to server, but when server response **Console returns: Assertion failed: undefined.**

Non-emscripten version of client written in pure Javascript by WebSocket Class, works great.

Someone have any idea ?

BTW. server is in C#,
I send to client,

```
byte[] send = new byte[5 + 2];
send[0] = 0x81; // last frame, text
send[1] = 5; // not masked, length 5
send[2] = (byte)'x';
send[3] = (byte)'Y';
send[4] = (byte)'z';
send[5] = (byte)'A';
send[6] = (byte)'B';
client.Send(send);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with data type, raw sockets created through emscripten MUST BE binary.
0x81 is text data, 0x82 is binary data.

send[0] = **0x82**; // last frame, **BINARY**